# Is there any utility in conceptualizing a 1D wavefunction as a space-curve?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

I was watching animations of different wavefunctions that occur in physics, and it annoyed me that the real and imaginary parts are often graphed on the same axis separately. I wanted to know whether there are any sources that treat a 1D wavefunction $\Psi(x,t):\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{C}$ as a time-varying curve in $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{C}$ with coordinates:

$$\vec r(x,t) = [x, \Re(\Psi(x,t)), \Im(\Psi(x,t))].$$

Then, things like arc-length, curvature, tension can be computed as though this were a curve in $\mathbb{R}^3$ changing through time. I was thinking about computing the curvative especially because it uses the acceleration of the curve, which requires us to compute $\frac{\partial^2\Psi}{\partial x^2}$, which is a quantity that appears in the Schrodinger equation.

I haven't given this too much time, but I was daydreaming as to whether the conceptualization has more to it than just a passing thought.